# Notation: in general is it ok to think of $p(y|x)$ as $p_x(y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, notation

In the notation for the conditional probability, $p(y|x)$, I believe *usually* we think of this with $x$ having a fixed value and $y$ varying, such that it integrates to one.

In this case, is it acceptable to instead write it, or think of it, as $p_x(y)$?

I.e.
$$
  p_x(y) \equiv p(y|x)
$$

Somehow I would find this to be more clear than the traditional conditional notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the best choice for notation. Such notation is commonly used in two scenarios.

First, you can see people writing $p_X(x)$, where they mean "value returned by probability distribution $p$ of *random variable* $X$ for $x$". In this case $p(x)$ is a less precise shorthand for $p_X(x)$. So if $X$ is random variable for heights of males and $Y$ is heights of females, then $p_X(y)$ means "what would be the probability of observing *female's* height $y$ according to the distribution of male heights $p_X$". Using this notation, people write $p_{X|Y}(x)$ to denote $p(X=x|Y)$. You can find many uses of this notation in [Wikipedia's article on conditional probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution).

Second common usage, is writing $f_\theta(x)$ for "probability density (or probability) returned by probability density (or mass) function $f$ *parametrized by* $\theta$ for $x$"<sup>†</sup>. In this case again $\theta$ is a *property* of $f$. So $f_\theta(x)$ is a different spelling of $f(x; \theta)$.

Moreover, you write

> In the notation for the conditional probability, $p(y|x)$, I believe
>   *usually* we think of this with $x$ having a fixed value and $y$ varying [...]

but notice that $P(X=x|Y=y)$ and $P(X=x|Y)$ are [*not* the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_a_random_variable), since in first case you ask about conditioning on *fixed* value of $Y$, while in the second case you ask about conditioning on *random variable*.

<sub><sup>†</sup> - There is nothing special about letter $f$, you can use any other letter in here, $f$ and $p$ are the two most popular choices.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use if you’re consistent in your notation (but I don't really suggest). Although widely used, $p(x), p(y), p(x|y),...$ are all abuse of notations. They’re ambigious, e.g. what is $p(2)$? $p$ doesn’t represent the pdf of a specific RV.

A better and fully unambigious way is to use $p_X(x)$, where subscript denotes the RV, and inside parantheses the specific value. This way we know which pdf we use.

Your new notation actually may cause people to think “put $y$ in the pdf of $x$”. If you’ll only read your notes, it’s OK upto some extent.

A bad case when you don’t use subscripts is the convolution of densities by the way:
$$\int f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx \ \ \text{vs} \ \ \int f(x)f(z-x)dx$$

In the RHS expression, it's totally ambiguous what $f(.)$ represents.