# Understanding conditional notation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, notation

Which is the correct way to describe the conditional probability distribution of X conditioned upon Y where X = a, Y = b
$$P_{X \mid Y}(a \mid b) \tag1$$ or $$P_{X \mid Y}(a,b) \tag2$$

What is the difference between the two? I have seen (1) written at places. But, $P_{X \mid Y}()$ is a function in x and y. So I don't see why (2) is not the notation to describe it and what ambiguities does (1) resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write it as $P(X=a|Y=b)$? If you want to use underscore notation, $P_{X|Y}(a|b)$ is the more common one, e.g. you can find it used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution). $P_{X, Y}(a, b)$ would be used for joint distribution, so the underscore is consistent with braces. The notation is [described in greater detail here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/399871/35989).

Comment: Your suggestion made me realise an improvement to my question. Making it. I guess you're suggestion doesn't make sense for continuous distributions. X = a is never happening.

Comment: Although your suggestion is often used for discrete variables, it is confusing for continuous variables, because--being the analog of writing "$f(X=x)$" for the conventional expression $f(X)$--it is pleonastic.

Comment: "$P_{X, Y}(a, b)$ would be used for joint distribution, so the underscore is consistent with braces." I did not mention this notation. I mentioned $P_{X \mid Y}(a,b)$. The information regarding the distribution to follow is in the subscript and the parentheses contain the values that the RVs involved take

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder yes and I refer to exactly that, the convention is to use “,” or “|” consistently between underscore and braces.

Comment: Ohhh. Okay. My bad. I see your point now